Deflation technique proof
I'm trying to prove the following theorem of Burden's Numerical Analysis Book:
Theorem:  Suppose $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$ with associated eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n$ and that $\lambda_1$ has multiplicity 1. Let $x$ be a vector with $x^tv_1 = 1$. Then the matrix:
$B = A − λ_1v_1x^t$
has eigenvalues $0, λ_2, λ_3, . . . , λ_n$ with associated eigenvectors $v_1, w_2, w_3,\cdots,w_n$, where $v_i$ and $w_i$ are related by the equation
$v_i = (λ_i − λ_1)w_i + λ_1(x^tw_i)v_1$
for each $i = 2, 3, . . . , n.$
My approach:
For $v_1$, $Bv_1 = (A-\lambda_1 v_1 x^t)v_1 = Av_1 - \lambda_1 v_1 = 0$, so the first eigenvalue for $B$ is $0$.
Here is the problem
Let: $w_i = cv_1 + v_i$, then operating and simplifyng:
\begin{align*}
(B-\lambda_i I)w_i &= (A - \lambda_i I)(cv_1 + v_i) - \lambda_1 v_1 x^t w_i\\
&= cAv_1+Av_i-c\lambda_iv_1-\lambda_iv_i- \lambda_1 v_1 x^t w_i\\
&= c\lambda_1 v_1 - c\lambda_i v_1 - \lambda_1 (x^t w_i) v_1\\
&= (c(\lambda_1 - \lambda_i) - \lambda_1 (x^t w_i)) v_1 = 0
\end{align*}
Then $c= - \dfrac{\lambda_1 (x^t w_i)}{(\lambda_i - \lambda_1)}$
but replacing it in:
$w_i = - \dfrac{\lambda_1 (x^t w_i)}{(\lambda_i - \lambda_1)}v_i + v_i$
I obtained this relation:
$(\lambda_i - \lambda_1)v_i = (\lambda_i - \lambda_1)w_i + \lambda_1 (x^t w_i) v_1$
Is there something wrong in some steps? Thanks in advance

Your $w_i$ is dependent on c so expressing c in terms of $w_i $ makes little sense
